# Proving a set of linear functionals is a basis for a dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've seen some similar problems on the stackexchange and I want to be sure I am at least approaching this in a way that is sensible.

The problem as stated:

Let $V= \Bbb R^3$ and define $f_1, f_2, f_3 \in V^*$ as follows:

$f_1(x,y,z)= x-2y ,\; f_2(x,y,z)= x+y+z,\;f_3(x,y,z)= y-3z$

Prove that $f_1, f_2, f_3$ is a basis for $V^*$ and and then find a basis for V for which it is the dual basis.

Here's my problem: the question feels a bit circular. But this is what I attempted:

To show that the linear functionals $f$ are a basis, we want that $f_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$, or that $f_i(x_j)=1$ if $i=j$ and that it is zero otherwise.

That means that  we want to set this up so that

$$1= f_1(x,y,z)= x-2y$$ 
$$0= f_2(x,y,z)= x+y +z$$ 
$$0= f_3(x,y,z)=   y-3z$$

That gives us three equations and three unknowns. Solving them we get $2x-2z=1$ for $x-z=\frac{1}{2}$ and $z=x-\frac{1}{2}$ and subbing into the equation for $f_3$ I get $0=y-3x-\frac{3}{2}$ which gets us $1=x-6x+3$ or $x=\frac{2}{5}$. That gives us $y=\frac{-3}{10}$ and $z=\frac{-1}{10}$.

OK, this is where I am stuck on the next step. I just got what should be a vertical matrix I think, with the values $(\frac{2}{5}, \frac{-3}{10}, \frac{-1}{10})$ but I am not sure where to go from here. I am not entirely sure I set this up correctly.

thanks
EDIT: I do know that I have to show that $f_1, f_2, f_3 $ are linearly independent. That I think I can manage, but I am unsure how to fit it into the rest of the problem or if I am even approaching this right.

Comment: Do you not know what "basis" means?

Comment: I understand that the basis is the linearly independent set of vectors that generates a space, yes. so I have to show that $f_1$ et al. are linearly independent, yes?

Comment: For the basis part: yes you are in a 3-dimensional space, and you have 3 vectors so all you have to do is show that they are linearly independent. (Generally, you have to show they span the space as well, but this is automatic by dimension considerations).

Comment: For the way you begin your work I think you're confusing stuff: you're not asked to prove $\,f_1,f_2,f_3\,$ are **the dual basis** in $\,V^*\,$ of some basis in $\,V\,$ , but *only* that they are linearly independent (since they are three and $\,\dim V^*=\dim V=3\,$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like you are on the right track.  But you have only worked out one basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  First, notice that we will have three vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ where $v_i = (x, y, z)$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$ (i.e. these are elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$).  So as you point out we want that

$$f_1(v_1) = 1, f_1(v_2) = 0, f_1(v_3) = 0$$
$$f_2(v_1) = 0, f_2(v_2) = 1, f_2(v_3) = 0$$
$$f_3(v_1) = 0, f_3(v_2) = 0, f_3(v_3) = 1$$

So you have some more equations to work with to find the other basis vectors (it looks like you have solved the first one).

**Edit**: And also, I think you can do the part to check that $f_1, f_2, f_3$ are linearly independent, but I will just write out what you want to start with:

Suppose you have $c_1, c_2, c_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$c_1f_1 + c_2f_2 + c_3f_3 = 0$$ i.e. $$c_1(x - 2y) + c_2(x + y + z) + c_3(y -3z) = 0$$

Then you want to show all $c_i = 0$ and that proves they are linearly independent.  (It is just a bit of manipulation to get that).

Comment: Yes, I wanted in part to make sure I wasn't doing something stupid. From here it looks like I can just do the same process for the other basis vectors, (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) and then I have the basis vectors, which shows that the $f_n$s are bases of V* (once I show they are linearly independent) and then we're done because I have the basis vectors for V as well, yes?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You know that the $f$'s are linearly independent and there are 3 of them so that they form a basis (in finite dimensions the dual space has the same dimension as the original space).  Then you will find a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that these $f$'s are dual to.

Comment: One thing though, I wouldn't think of the $f$'s as vectors of the form $(x, y, z)$ they are functions which take as inputs vectors $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and output a real number.  It is just convenient to write $f_1(x,y,z) = x -2y$, but really to be more correct it should be understand that you are applying $f_1$ to any vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$. This is why they are called *functionals*. This may clear some things up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Finite-dimensional_case

Answer (score 2):

What about a direct approach? Suppose $\,a,b,c\in\Bbb R\,$ are such that

$$af_1+bf_2+cf_3=0\in V^*\implies\;\forall\,v:=(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\;,\;\;af_1v+bf_2v+cf_3v=0\iff$$

$$a(x-2y)+b(x+y+z)+c(y-3z)=0\iff$$

$$\iff (a+b)x-(2a-b-c)y+(b-3c)z=0$$

As the above is true for **all** $\;x,y,z\in\Bbb R\,$ , we must have

$$\begin{align*}\text{I}&\;\;\;\;a+b=0\\\text{II}&\;\;\;\;2a-b-c=0\\\text{II}&\;\;\;\;b-3c=0\end{align*}\;\;\implies a=-b\;,\;\;c=3a=\frac13b\implies a=b=c=0$$

and we're done.

Comment: I was editing mine at the same time you posted this, sorry for the duplicate information.  It sounded like to me the op was not having trouble proving $f_1, f_2, f_3$ we're a basis, but instead trying to find the basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that $f_1, f_2, f_3$ we're the dual basis to.

Comment: No need to apologize, @RyanSullivant : this happens all the time since some write slower than others, in particular with basic questions like this one.